# Laravel installation in Bluehost getting error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()?

Tags: php, laravel, installation, shared-hosting

I try to host my Laravel application in **BlueHost** i follow this tutorial [LINK](http://blog.stickyrice.net/archives/2014/laravel-putty-shared-hosting/comment-page-1/#comment-59468)

i installed composer succesfully when i create new project in last line im getting this error 
[image]
i tried **php artisan** command but its showing same error. can any one help on this Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i solved my problem after the installation i used

**php-cli artisan clear-compiled** insted of `php artisan clear-compiled`
and we can use artisan command like this `php-cli artisan ......`